Impossibile to scale dynos in Heroku
I have created a project in java 1.8, adding a file named 'Procfile' in the root, containing the instruction:
worker: sh target/bin/workerBot

and inserted in the pom build the reference:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>org.eurov.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>workerBot</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

I registered in heroku and created an app with buildpack 'heroku/java' then deployed regularly (I used the deploy linked to the github project, not through the local project)
Then from cmd I launched in order:
heroku login --> logging in correctly
heroku logs --tail --app myAppName --> getting the build logs
heroku ps:scale worker=1 --app myAppName --> getting the error:

Scaling dynos... !
    ! Couldn't find that process type (worker).

I searched around for similar problems and followed the procedures, but my problem remains.
The only difference from the vast majority of projects is that I didn't load it from a local repository, however the CLI commands work, so it shouldn't be a problem.
Also, I have the checkmark in Heroku to automatically update the project taken from Github.
What else can I try?
Thanks
Answer to Chris:

Yes, it's called exactly 'Procfile'


This is the project structure:


Procfile has been commited and pushed yesterday in the github repo:



And I've already built and deployed successfully on Heroku, so I think it must be in UTF-8 otherwise it should have failed in parsing: herokuticket
Thank you Chris, it was exactly as you said.
I was dumb.. but at least now I have learned :)

Something is wrong with your Procfile. Is it called Procfile exactly (capital P, lowercase ocfile, no extension)? Is it encoded as UTF-8? Is it committed, and included in the commit you're deploying?

"I have created a project in java 1.8, adding a file named 'Procfile' in the root"—that's not the root directory. Root means the top-level project directory. Move it up several directories so it's beside your .gitignore file, then commit and redeploy.

Thank you Chris, it was exactly as you said. I was dumb.. but at least now I have learned :)

It's not dumb to make mistakes, especially if you learn from them. Glad you got it working.
